# Can I switch from background mode to foreground mode from WatchOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I'm going to make an Apple Watch app.
The function I want is to turn on the app automatically in certain situations.
After setting the background mode first using WKBackground Modes, I want my app to turn on and run certain functions when my heart rate reaches 130.

Is this possible?

If not, is it only possible to give Notification?

Comment: The only way you can reliably monitor heart rate is to be a workout app running the active workout session.  Active workout apps can remain as the default "on screen" app when the wrist is raised, just like Apple's workout app does.  However, it is unlikely the user will be looking at their watch continually so you would want to post a notification with appropriate haptics and sound.

Comment: Then, is it possible to use a certain function at that time? I want to run the timer function. @Paulw11

Comment: At what time?  Your code is responsible for analysing the incoming workout data and examining the heart rate.  You can't simply configure a "trigger" to fire under certain heart rate conditions.  You can't start a timer on the in-built Timer app if that is what you are asking